# Get a specific column value from a table when query through linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
var Sent =  request.Transactions.First(x => x.isSent == "4");
```

1. When the above query runs it gets the complete list of a table row
   when condition meets. I just want a specific column value
   `Date_Sent`.
2. Can I also create a if statement to check if the `Date_Sent` is null
   or not?

Comment: What do you mean with "complete list"? "First" returns just one transaction object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The`First` returns an item of the  collection's type. Simple access it's property.

```
var sent = request.Transactions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.isSent=="4")?.Data_Sent;

If(sent == null) { }
```

See 2 things:

- I suggest you use `FirstOrDefault` instead. It will not throw an exception if no item in sequence match predicate.
- Use the `?.` to access the property. It is called Null Propagation

If you do want to use the `.Select` then thr nicer way without creating temporary anonymous objects or breaking it into separate commands is to use the query syntax instead like this:

```
var sent = (from item in request.Transactions
            where item.isSent =="4"
            select Sent_Data).FirstOrDefault()
```

*By the way I'd recommend looking into naming conventions in C#*

Comment: @amir - If you are still looking for it then it is on the left side just under the number of upvotes of this answer. A grey V. Will turn green if you select it